# Marshal array of strings c# to MQL4

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling, mql4

This code marshals a single `string` correctly

I want to marshal array of strings.

```
[DllExport("Call", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]      
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static string Call(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string parameters,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string host)
{
    try
    {
        string resultValue = "some string";
        return resultValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: You first need an oracle that says how many elements are in the array.  You don't have one.

Comment: 10 elements in  array as string[] str=new string(10);

Comment: Use the MarshalAs.SizeConst property.